# Ground state energy for commuting local Hamiltonians

Tags: complexity-theory

I am going through S. Gharibian's course on quantum complexity theory (https://groups.uni-paderborn.de/fg-qi/data/QCT_Masterfile.pdf) and encountered the following problem (**Ex 6.39**, note that here $\lambda_{\text{min}}()$ stands for the smallest eigenvalue):

[image]

Does anyone know how to approach this problem? Personally I am not even convinced that the statement is true! Suppose that there are two normal operators $A, B$ with the computational basis as their common eigenbasis, $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 10 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$B = \begin{pmatrix} 10 & 0 \\ 0 & 5 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Clearly, $$A+B = \begin{pmatrix} 11 & 0 \\ 0 & 15 \end{pmatrix}$$ and $$\lambda_{\text{min}}(A+B) = 11,$$ which is different than $\lambda_{\text{min}}(A) + \lambda_{\text{min}}(B) = 1 + 5 = 6$.

What went wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Please, do not post screen shots of theorems, codes, etc. Rather use quote environment. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Your reasoning looks sound to me! For the rest of the proof, it would be sufficient to say $\lambda_{\min}(A+B)\geq\lambda_{\min}(A)+\lambda_{\min}(B)$ wouldn't it? And it is true that the bound can be saturated for the commuting case.

Comment: @DaftWullie What did you mean by the bound being saturated? And why would two commuting operators guarantee that? Thanks!

Comment: All I was saying is that there exist cases where $\lambda_{\min}(A+B)=\lambda_{\min}(A)+\lambda_{\min}(B)$, and these are particularly easy to construct for commuting operators (but I agree that not all commuting operators satisfy this).

Comment: @DaftWullie I suppose the only commuting operators that satisfy the equality are those with non-decreasing ordered eigenvalues

Comment: @user896578 Well, at least they have to share a single common eigenvector in their ground state spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the note you provided and believe there should be a implicit condition for normal operators $A$ and $B$, which seems not to be stated explicitly in the note. If
$$\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2\leq...\leq \lambda_n$$ is the eigenvalue for $A$, you should always apply a permutation such that the the diagonalized $A$ is
$$
diag\{\lambda_1, \lambda_2... \lambda_n\}
$$
and the same for $B$.

In your case, you should define $B=diag\{5, 10\}$ instead.

Comment: Thanks @Yunzhe for your comment. Is the permutation you mentioned a trivial operation that can always be done with poly time for any normal matrices? An example or a reference to where I can read into more would be great thanks!

Comment: There are many [sorting algorithms](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/notes/sorting-and-searching-algorithms-time-complexities-cheat-sheet/) that only requires polynomial time complexity (more precisely, $O(n^2)$). As the permutation operations are actually sorting operations, I don't think it will add any overhead in the context of complexity class.